# Opening Node-RED editor page from Java web application

Tags: java, node.js, button, web-applications, node-red

I would like to have a button(html) in my Java web application that once clicked it opens up the Node-RED editor page. I've tried using https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/runtime/embedding to no success, I don't know how to make the page appear (It's my first time working on a project like this).

I also would like the editor to already contain a flow generated dynamically: the application has an XML of a tree and for every node of the tree the flow will contain a function node connected to the parent and the child nodes.

How should I go about it ? Is there an API to create the flow given the structure in XML/JSON ?

EDIT: Giving more context: I'm trying to run multiple instances for different users. I would like the users, once chosen the tree structure, to be able to press the "export to node red" button and open up the Node-RED editor and have a flow of function nodes inside with same structure as the tree and with predetermined JavaScript code inside. To give and example, given the xml of a tree with just a root node and two children I would like this to be the result of the button press:[image]

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve here? Is this a single instance of Node-RED or are you trying to run multiple instances for different users? The question is currently both far too broad, you need to be a lot more specific if we are going to be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is not a simple task.

Running multiple instances of Node-RED for different users requires a framework to configure and totally and start separate Node-RED while maintaining separation between them.

I would setup up an instance of [FlowFuse](https://flowfuse.com/) and use the [API](https://flowfuse.com/docs/api/) to spin up instances and setup the user (probably using SSO).

The only bit that is currently missing from the API would be a way of injecting the flow into the instance (it could be done with a little Database work), but support for things like that is on the list to be added soon.

You can then either redirect the user to the Node-RED editor or embed the editor in your web app in an iframe.

Full disclosure I work for FlowFuse.

Comment: Would it be easier with a single instance of Node-RED ? This is for a school project so I have some leeway to simplify the project

Comment: For a single instance then you would `Runtime.exec()` to run Node-RED, you would write the flow to `flow.json` and save this into the `userDir` that you pass on the Node-RED command line.

Comment: Is there a simple way to create the flow.json given the tree structure or should I learn how they are created in the editor and reverse engineer it ?

Comment: There is nothing that will create them for you, but they are pretty simple and self explanatory.